# Plot a column with labels of another column over time in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a table in Pandas dataframe (python) where I want to plot one column with labels from another column over a time column.

For example:

```
fruit | fruit_count | datestamp 
apple    20           03-2018
kiwi     10           03-2018
mango    35           03-2018
apple    16           04-2018
kiwi     18           04-2018
mango    40           04-2018
.        .              .
.        .              .
apple    50           03-2020
kiwi     70           03-2020
mango    120          03-2020
```

Basically it would be one plot where the x-axis is the datestamp (03-2018, 04-2018, ..., 03-2020) and there would be 3 line plots - one for apple, kiwi, and mango with 3 corresponding labels.

Currently, I try to do it by just parsing the unique fruit names from the dataframe

`fruits = list(set(fruit_df['fruit'].tolist()))`
and then I loop through and plot each one

```
for fruit in fruits:
    fruit_df[fruit_df['fruit'] == fruit].plot(x='datestamp', y='fruit_count')
```

Is there a better way to do this which would do this all in one line and would plot everything on one graph instead of 3 different ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options. If you really want a **one-line** solution you'll want `seaborn`, or to reshape your data using `pivot`

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

N = 20
df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['apple', 'kiwi', 'mango']*N,
                   'date_stamp': np.repeat(pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='1M',  periods=N), 3),
                   'fruit_count': np.random.randint(1,100, N*3)})
```

---

#### Seaborn

You use `hue` to specify the groups.

```
sns.lineplot(data=df, hue='fruit', x='date_stamp', y='fruit_count')
```

#### pandas.DataFrame.groupby

Similar to your current implementation, but you can use `groupby` to split into the sub-Frames.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for fruit, gp in df.groupby('fruit'):
    gp.plot(x='date_stamp', y='fruit_count', ax=ax, label=fruit)
```

#### pandas.pivot

Pivot before plotting, then you just need a single plot call

```
df.pivot(index='date_stamp', columns='fruit', values='fruit_count').plot()
```

---

#### Output*

Axes and labeling slightly different between methods. This is the groupby output.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case, the combination of `datestamp` and `fruit` are `non-unique`:

```
fruit_df.groupby(['datestamp', 'fruit'])['fruit_count'].sum().unstack().plot(kind='bar')
```

In case, the combination is `unique`, this should also work:

```
df.pivot(index='datestamp', columns='fruit', values='fruit_count').plot(kind='bar')
```